# Power cord for laptop power adaptor with different vottage.

Tags: power-supply, cable, adapter, laptop

Greeting's, I have googled this question but the answers seem confusing without much explanation. I would appreciate if the community here solves this once and for all. :)

Real world scenario: My laptops power adapter is 180w with acceptable input between 100-240V~ 50-60Hz 2.5A with original cable having 2.5A with 125V~. Due to pin difference, I am contemplating using a cable from different brand with 2.5A and 250V~ rating.

Here are my questions:

1. Is this OK?
2. If yes / no, why?
3. What parameters does one have to consider when using different cables / adapters?

While I did find few answers saying using the alternate cable is OK. I did not find the explanation as to why and what does one have to keep in mind before making such a decision.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `The term rated in any electrical equipment,wheather its RATED VOLTAGE or RATED CURRENT means it is the maximum value of current,voltage or any other parameter beyond which the machine will not be operating according toits desired operation.Beyond the rated value the machine may have some faults or damages and the ...` if you google for `rated voltage `

Comment: Hence in my case the adapter has rating of 2.5A with 240V~ and the cable supplied with it has 125~ rating. I am replacing this with a cable with 250V~ with 2.5A being same on both. Based on your response this is OK since the cable is rated over the adapter and I know I'm not using that much power. Am I correct or I am missing something? Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My laptop's power adapter is 180 W with acceptable input between 100 - 240V~ 50 - 60 Hz, 2.5A with original cable having 2.5A with 125V~.

- Power is the product of voltage and current: P = VI.
- At 100 V your laptop will require 1.8 A (if the PSU is 100% efficient).
- At 200 V it will require 0.9A.
- Manufacturer reckons worst case, with lowest input voltage and startup surge is 2.5 A.
- Cable insulation must be rated for the maximum voltage the cable will be exposed to.

> Due to pin difference, I am contemplating using a cable from different brand with 2.5A and 250V~ rating.
>
> Q1. Is this OK?

Yes.

> If yes / no, why?

See above.

> What parameters does one have to consider when using different cables / adapters?

See above.